# Mutation Observer not working as expected with CefSharp

Tags: javascript, c#, winforms, cefsharp, mutation-observers

I have a WinForms project with the CefSharp *ChromiumWebBrowser* control.

I have the following JavaScript in a file

```
var msgTypes = Object.freeze({ 
  MessageReceived: 0
});

var config = {
  childList: true,
  subtree: true
};

var callback = function(mutations, observer) {
 mutations.forEach((mutation) => {
  if (mutation.addedNodes.length > 0) 
  {
    var msgs = mutation.addedNodes.querySelectorAll('.message');
    if (msgs != null && msgs.length > 0)
    {
      for(const msg of msgs)
      {
          var text = msg.querySelectorAll('.message-text');
          if (text != null && text.length > 0)
          {
            CefSharp.PostMessage({"messageType": msgTypes.MessageReceived, "data":{ "text": text[0].innerText }});
          }
      }
    }
  }
  });
};

var body = document.querySelector('body');

var observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

  // Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
//var observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

// Start observing the target node for configured mutations
observer.observe(body, config);
```

The C# code below executes the JavaScript above by the CefSharp *ChromiumWebBrowser* web browser control in a Form in the project mentioned above.

```
public async Task ExecuteAsync(ScriptType type)
        {
            string fileName = string.Join('-', Regex.Split(type.ToString(), @"(?<!^)(?=[A-Z])")).ToLower();
            string filePath = Path.Combine(Globals.AppPath, "js", $"{fileName}.js");
            string jsCode = await File.ReadAllTextAsync(filePath);
            browser.ExecuteScriptAsync(jsCode);
        }
```

Where *browser* is the WinForms *ChromiumWebBrowser* control.

Below is the code that executes the JavaScript above when the main frame has finished loading for the CefSharp  *ChromiumWebBrowser* control.

```
private async void WebBrowser_FrameLoadEnd(object? sender, FrameLoadEndEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Frame.IsMain && !frameLoaded)
                await ExecLoadJs();

            if (frameLoaded)
                return;
            else
                frameLoaded = true;

        }
```

Below is the code that attaches a handler to the *JavaScriptMessageReceived* event (which is fired when the `CefSharp.PostMessage` is called from the JS code above.

```
           webBrowser.JavascriptMessageReceived += WebBrowser_JavascriptMessageReceived;
           webBrowser.FrameLoadEnd += WebBrowser_FrameLoadEnd;
```

Below is the handler code mentioned above.

```
private void WebBrowser_JavascriptMessageReceived(object? sender, JavascriptMessageReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            HandleMessageReceived(e);
        }
```

The problem is that the handler above only gets fired when the is page loaded. Afterwards, when the DOM changes in real-time, the handler no longer gets fired. So it seems like the MutationObserver is not working as it should with the CefSharp *ChromiumWebBrowser* control. However, the same JavaScript code works correctly in a Chrome Extension (omitted from this) I created that does the same; that is, the MutationObserver in the Chrome Extension is constantly detecting real-time DOM changes. This appear a very difficult problem to solve. A solution/code sample would be much appreciated.

Attached the debugger, ran the project in debug mode with VS and was
expecting the WebBrowser_JavascriptMessageReceived to fire continuously after DOM changes. However, the breakpoint only fires after the page loads.

Comment: You can open `Devtools` and debug the javascript, get a better understanding of what's going on. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Trouble-Shooting#javascript-debugging